# We can never have more than $\frac{n}{2}$ edges of a graph $G$ of order $n$ that are colored the same. Why?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I was going through the text: *A First Course in Graph Theory* by *Chartrand, Zhang*, where I came across the following claim, [here graph $G$ is of order $n$] :

> Any two edges of $G$ that are colored the same cannot be adjacent of course. This says that we can never have more than $\frac{n}{2}$ edges of $G$ that are colored the same.

Which means that maximum number of non-adjacent vertices in a graph $G$ is $\frac{n}{2}$. The text does not give any reason or logic behind the same, which makes me feel that this fact is quite obvious and can be obtained quite intuitively. But I could not quite obtain it intuitively but rather I tried out a sort of small proof.

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. Let $G$ be such that $C_n$ is a subgraph of $G$.

[The number $\frac{n}{2}$ made me feel that we are using the alternate edges from the maximum possible cycle in the graph.]

[image: diagram]

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$*The edges highlighted with yellow indicate the non adjacent edges in the graph*

If $n$ is even in the above diagram we shall attain the number $\frac{n}{2}$ of non adjacent edges.

But suppose,of the sake of contradiction, there were $\frac{n}{2}+1$ non adjacent edges. But since the edges highlighted in yellow have covered all the vertices in $C_n$, not is impossible for us to incorporate another edges $e$, which is not adjacent to any of the above yellow edges. So we arrive at a contradiction.

But is it possible to understand the above bound more intuitively (unlike [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3526708/606943) where a rigorous proof is asked, but my main intention is not to get a proof but rather understand the claim, in an intuitive manner, which even the authors I guess had in their minds, while writing the book) ?

Comment: which claim of mine?

Comment: it is not my claim. It is the author's claim. :( But suppose, as you say $G=K_2 \cup K_2$, then we have two isolated edges, which we can color the same, now the graph has $n=4$ and the max no. of edges which we can color the same is $2=\frac{4}{2}$. I do not get your point

Comment: Oh!  I assumed $n$ meant the number of edges.  Rereading, I see that it's number of vertices.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention the fact that $G$ is of order $n$. Actually, the book assumes it throughout the text, so did not mention it explicitly before the excerpt...

Comment: @HallaSurvivor not really, the answer given there is fine but not intuitive. It is a rigorous one. Thanks for the help anyways. :)

Comment: No two edges of the same colour share a vertex. So each edge of that colour "uses up" its two vertices. There are only $n$ vertices available. So $n/2$ edges already use up all the vertices, and adding another edge of that colour forces a vertex to be shared.

Comment: I've posted an answer at the duplicate question now, hopefully it now answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edges that are coloured the same cannot be adjacent.
If there are more than $n/2$ edges of the same colour, the total number of vertices is more than $n$ (each edge contributes $2$ vertices and by the colouring assumption, no vertex is incident at two of these edges), that is, $n>n$.
This is, of course, absurd.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: "no `edge` is incident at two of these `vertices`" instead of " no `vertex` is incident at two of these `edges`" ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: No, the point is that each edge gives you a vertex you didn't see before (it wasn't incident to a previous edge).

Comment: @JacobManaker ok got it... I was just thinking probably the same thing, but with a different English sentence.